# Cannot debug under Visual Studio Express anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, monodevelop

I used to be able to debug using Visual C# Express 2010 with no problem before. However, since I've opened my project using MonoDevelop (to port it under MacOS), I can't seem to be able to debug anymore.

The exact error message is available below:

[image: The exact error message]

A lot of people says to go in the configuration manager, which I'm familiar with, however, I can't seem to find it in the Express version.

Comment: Added the monodevelop tag to see if anybody monitoring that can help you.

Comment: make a backup and try deleting everything in bin\debug\ and rebuild entire solution

Comment: Re. configuration manager, enable expert settings first. `Tools->Settings->ExpertSettings`. Then find it under `Build->ConfigurationManager`

Comment: have you gone through this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo

Comment: @jValdron: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643659/c-sharp-debugging-issue-no-symbols-are-loaded-for-any-call-stack-frame

Comment: FFS! Thanks @GeorgeDuckett! I thought it was because I had the Express edition that I was missing a lot of features, turns out I was just used to the Professional edition, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As George Duckett said:

Re. configuration manager, enable expert settings first. Tools->Settings->ExpertSettings. Then find it under Build->ConfigurationManager

Then changed it to Debug.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't have this issue prior to opening in Monodevelop, it more than likely changed something within the solution and/or project files. There are a number of posts on stackoverflow...

[stackoverflow: no symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

[stackoverflow: no symbols when crossing module boundries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643659/c-sharp-debugging-issue-no-symbols-are-loaded-for-any-call-stack-frame)
(From Răzvan Panda comment on the question)

... that talk about missing symbols. However, based on the information provided about monodevelop, I'd venture to guess that the IDE changed something within the solution and/or project files.

If your solution is under source control and you don't see any differences in these files, let me know. Otherwise, you could create a new blank solution/project file (from Visual C# Express 2010) and re-add all your files to it to get the default settings back and see if that resolves your issue.

EDIT: Also, keep in mind that there are ".user" files that I guess "might" have an effect on build/debugging configurations. If re-adding your files to blank solution/project files doesn't work make sure all the "extra" files like ".user" are not in the directory. Usually files like "*.csproj.user", and "*.suo".  I've never had an issue deleting these they store local configuration changes that are not usually checked into source control.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Symbols when I added some dll to my project so what I did was to manually adding them. you can try going to tools > option > Debugging > Symbols   and from there you can add the file root (in this case monoDevelop) and it automatically looks for all .pdb files and adds them to your environment. After rebuild it should be Okay.

Cheers